# Is apt-get upgrade a dangerous command?

Tags: 12.04, apt

When I use apt-get update and apt-get upgrade,there are some packages should installed in newest version,like below:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apport apt apt-transport-https apt-utils binutils
  cloud-init cpp-4.8 dpkg fuse g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gdisk gnupg gpgv
  grub-common grub-legacy-ec2 grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common initscripts
  isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libaccountsservice0 libapparmor-perl
  libapparmor1 libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libasan0 libatomic1 libbsd0
  libcurl3-gnutls libdrm2 libedit2 libfuse2 libgcc-4.8-dev libgd3 libgomp1
  libitm1 libjson-c2 libjson0 libnuma1 libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev
  libstdc++6 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtsan0 libudev1 libxext6
  linux-libc-dev ntpdate openssl overlayroot patch policykit-1 ppp
  python-urllib3 python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-update-manager
  rsyslog systemd-services sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tcpdump tzdata udev
  update-manager-core
75 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

If I didn't know every one of there packages what will happen if there update in newest version.I shouldn't execute this command(apt-get upgrade).

For example:

This php version is before I upgrade

```
yzxu@ubuntu:/tmp/git-2.1.2$ php --version
PHP 5.6.6-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

and after I upgrade:

```
yzxu@ubuntu:/tmp/git-2.1.2$ php --version
PHP 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

The php version is changed.And if I didn't what what was change in two version,should I upgrade it?Is it will **influence product**?

Comment: well that depends on the package version numbering scheme

Comment: @Mr.Gosh So if I want use upgrade,I should notice  every packages version numbering scheme and make sure every update didn't influence product?

Comment: no not necessarily-  if you are not sure if a package that you depend on is breaking something - you have to research. In php the version numbereing scheme is x.y.z where x = main version number (change this and it breaks things) x = feature number (here will things change too - but it is all well documented and should be no problem thorugh dependency checks of ubuntu) z = bugfix release (these wont normally break things and should allways be isntalled fast)

Comment: @Mr.Gosh I have see **apt-get** upgrade in many documents on github or other website.It looks like author   didn't care what will happen if user use **apt-get upgrade**  to update they system. It seems they just regard **apt-get upgrade** as a normal command instead of dangerous command like **rm -rf**

Comment: well it is something that canonical tests a lot before releasing the stuff to its users - so you normally should rely on the fact that apt-get upgrade doesn't destroy something - if it does - the software you use or your server is not under your full control. if you rely on your system - you need a staging system for tests - to be sure that apt-get upgrade is not a problem...

Comment: It's only dangerous if you *don't* use it.

Answer (score 17):

```
apt-get update
```

Refreshes the repositories and fetches information about packages that are available online.

```
apt-get upgrade
```

Downloads and installs updates for all installed packages - as long as it doesn't bother dependencies (install new packages, remove old ones or crosses a repo source (switch a package from one repo to another)).

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Does the same as "upgrade" but upgrades a package also when dependencies or sources are changed (something you want to avoid on servers without further testing).

To conclude - an update can break things but it is necessary!
So if you are on a desktop you should normally do a:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Without destroying something.

On a server most of the times a:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should be enough AND security updates should be installed automatically (on servers and desktops)

**Update to 16.04**

Meanwhile the "apt" wrapper is the standard way in Ubuntu, so the commands are now:

```
sudo apt update        #to update the repo-information

sudo apt upgrade       #to install all security fixes and changes that doesn't harm the system or change the behaviour

sudo apt full-upgrade  #the new "dist-upgrade" that installs newer versions that can break backwards-compatibility
```

**TL;DR!**

Yes, you should update PHP in this example because it is a security fix (this can be seen through the versioning scheme of PHP; it also wouldn't have been pushed into the "upgrade" channel of Ubuntu.)

Comment: Good advice on the `dist-upgrade` option for servers, as it can often do away with your config files! +1

Comment: I'm understand diff between upgrade and dist-upgrade.My puzzled is if I didn't know what actually change between two version,should I upgrade it?Maybe it will influence product.

Comment: hum.. But it is dangerous?  I have a good *16.04 LTS* , with the  `apt-get upgrade`  command I will lose **the LTS warranty**?

Comment: no - you won't - LTS means that you get new updates in the "upgrade" channel for a longer time than in the non-LTS version...

Comment: How to know when apt-get upgrade is finish?

Comment: well - when you get your prompt back, if it wanna do something it still asks for permission unless you trigger it with "-y"

Answer (score 3):

I have 3 years experience of using Ubuntu, from 16.04 LTS 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

I used to do upgrade before, like doing

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

or when System Updater pops up, click install as most of people suggested online and I trusted them. I think that upgrade would make the system more stable, more better and more secure, but actually it made more problems...
These behaviours had caused many many bugs so that I had spent lots of time debugging or reinstalling my system. For examples, broken grub, broken wifi driver, broken nvidia driver, broken DNS resolver... etc.

And recently, I have figured it out.

My opinion is not never doing upgrade. The reason why I always got lots of bugs is that `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade a lots of packages you do not know. If one of these packages do something wrong, there would cause some bugs.
The more packages you upgrade, the more risk your system would encounter. So my solution would be always upgrade specific packages you want to upgrade by doing so:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install <packages name>`

And when you want to do `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it takes risks.
If the system go well, lucky.
If not, debug or reinstall.

But how about security update, is it still safe?

In the Software & Updates, Updates section, if you choose security updates as the options "Download and install automatically", `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade` would handle the security update automatically.

You can check by

`less /var/log/apt/history.log`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. But you should regularly update your system. Updates can have risk, yes. This risk also depends on things I do not know such as what PPAs you may or may not have added or other sources. But again in general it's a good idea to keep you system up to date. When you update, you get stability fixes and security updates. So I will say that it is even more dangerous not to update(upgrade) your system.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `apt-get upgrade`it updates all installed packages on your system.
It is perfectly safe (unless you cut it off before it finishes) as all packages are from the repos (you should only install one's you trust) and are (probably) well tested before uploading.

The only small risk is a risk of bugs within the packages there self, but this could happen to any thing on any OS that was upgraded as bugs are common in any software and come and go based on version.

Should you upgrade ? Well thats up to you, I would say yes, if you don't like `upgrade` use the `application-updater` app, same thing no output to make you worried.

[Here is some documentation for `apt` so you can find out more](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apt-get.html)

Comment: hum... But it is "LTS dangerous"?  I have a good *16.04 LTS* , with the  `apt-get upgrade`  command I will lose **the LTS warranty**?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't know what you mean, all upgrade does is update the current system, it will not change your Ubuntu version, just update current packages.

Comment: thanks your reply. Example: if `apt-get upgrade` command changes from 16.04 LTS to 17 (or any other 16.X non-LTS), I will lost "LTS warranty".  If  no confusion and upgrade stay in the LTS subversion, ok.

Comment: that wont do that, it upgrades packages, not the OS, the command you use for that is do-release-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to other more complete answers, here is a corner case in which `apt-get upgrade` can be dangerous (I got caught in this myself):

When running Docker containers, `apt-get upgrade` will shut down all of them down.

This could cause:

- service disruption
- loss of data (if you have `--rm` in your `docker run` command for example, and have some data you value in the container itself and not mounted somewhere properly).

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes you may have a broken system, when you add third party PPA on your repository , after updating it `sudo apt-get update`.
It is not dangerous and actually you should do this to keep your system up-to-date. One suggestion from me though, just uncheck proposed and backports repository from software sources.

Comment: -1 Don't see how this addresses the question about `upgrade`

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

- This only updates all your Installed Softwares.
- This is Also Necessary when you Installed OS for the first time.. As it firstly needs Update, then only Enables you to use the Installed Softwares..

**Edit:**
And Upgrade is Used to Upgrade the packages which were not installed correctly..

Comment: I thought that `update` is for updating the package lists, and `upgrade` to update the packages. And `dist-upgrade` to update installed packages + install new packages

Comment: -1 This is wrong `update` just updates the sources and `upgrade` updates the packages